# Should a tag be used only under language-standard fitting questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

In a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52710838/557306)  about a unknown language feature,
a user tagged the question with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). This makes sense to
me, considering the code is in fact C.

On  the  other  hand,  the   unknown  parts  of  the  syntax
represented compiler extensions features, not strict part of
the language  standard. A moment later  another user removed
the C tag with the argument:

> this  question  uses  gcc-specific  extensions  (and  asks
>   specifically about them), thus  this question is off-topic
>   for C and on-topic for gcc.

It is  important to note  that the extensions  discussed are
not exclusive to  the GCC compiler, they exist  in others as
well.  However the  inclusion  or not  of  the language  tag
remains  an  open  question.  To my  eyes  including  it  is
relevant, since the code is C and at the questioner point of
view it is inevitably a unknown *language* feature (if known
to be an extension, the  question would be worded completely
differently). However to the editor's eyes, the language tag
is off topic since an extension  is not part of the standard
described in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info):

> This tag should be  used with general questions concerning
>   the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard […]

Should  a  language  tag  only be  used  when  the  question
included standardized features?

Comment: It is a never-ending battle between the purists and the pragmatists, a division created by the language standard being but a comprise that had to make everybody equally unhappy and every compiler having extensions to write practical programs.  Avoid getting involved in that battle, you can't win.

Comment: @HansPassant *never-ending battle* --> Not really in SO C/C++ community, the purists *overwhelmingly* win. Just take a look at the fantastic tag [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), so many upvotes averagely no matter how useless most of them are in actual development. SO community is so obsessed in standard, as if the standard text is more important than development itself. The unfortunate thing is, this meta post can't change anything.

Comment: Hmya, the programmers that need help with their [c] or [c++] program are almost never purists.  Just like compiler writers are not.  They don't get much practical assistance from a finger-wagging community, the commenting tends to especially get out of hand badly.  Didn't use to be that way, but the [pragmatists got chased away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374437/how-to-handle-other-users-rude-behaviour-towards-new-users).  That one was especially sad btw.

Comment: Entirely non-serious suggestion: How about we create a [tag:pure-c] tag? Then we can keep [tag:c] on such questions and everyone can be happy.

Comment: @HansPassant After some reading I realized that deleted user is hvd, that's really unbelievable. The comment in that post about VS is as ridiculous as this one about gcc. I doubt some particular users actually write any non-trivial C/C++ program in their life, maybe standard reading is their job.

Comment: @liliscent I wouldn't call language-lawyer questions useless. When faced with two compilers disagreeing on the legality/meaning of something, I want to know which one is right in order to provide the proper condition for the pragmatic workaround (i.e. should I be doing `#if GCC then workaround()` or `#if MSVC then workaround()`?). As compilers improve or new compilers/platforms are added to a project, knowing that is important. I usually find it in the standard myself instead of asking here, but not everyone is well-versed in standardese, so for them a language-lawyer question is the way to go

Comment: @Angew Yeah, calling it "useless" might be a little too far. What I wanted to say in previous comments was the disproportionate focus on the standard I've observed here. As for compiler bugs, in my experience, they're usually only revealed from overuse of some obscure feature or introduce of artificial language complexities, which often could be avoided by more "natural" and explicit alternatives. But to exploit the power of C++ as much as possible, being a language-lawyer might be beneficial. That's kinda opinion-based.

Comment: @liliscent also "I doubt some particular users actually write any non-trivial C/C++ program in their life" is rude, who are you to judge people ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my view, the tag C is appropriate when the base language for the question is C.

It is appropriate to *also* tag the question with auxilliary tags such as GCC if asking about a GCC extension.  If you are editing the question, it might be appropriate to add the auxilliary tag; it is not appropriate to remove the base language tag.

I've just been dealing with a question asking about `strlcat()`.  It isn't a part of Standard C or POSIX, but it is widely available.  It is perfectly OK (IMNSHO) to leave that question tagged with C and not worry about the fact that it's available on Linux and the *BSD systems (including macOS).  Questions about the Windows API in C should be tagged with C and WinAPI ([winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)), but they're still C questions (mostly — when they're not really about C++).

As noted in the comments, the person asking the question is frequently not aware of the minutiae of where the function or feature comes from.  That should not prevent them asking about it — Stack Overflow is where you can ask questions and get answers to them.

Removing the C tag from a question because it isn't about standard C (but is clearly about a dialect of C, rather than C++) is a hostile act — it is not friendly or welcoming, nor is it helpful.  It won't get the question the exposure it deserves.  I don't think people will try to guess what other tags to monitor than the base language; I know I don't often go searching for C questions other than via the C tag, for all I do monitor some extra tags, like [c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99) or [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc).

Where the question includes C++ code (`#include <iostream>` or similar), then it is appropriate to retag to C++ (see the recent discussion about [Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)) — but it isn't appropriate to remove the correct base language altogether.

I believe similar comments apply to C++.  I won't pretend to pontificate on most other languages.  I do note that the SQL tag requests the OP to also identify the DBMS on which the SQL should run because the standard language is not the same as any of the multitude of dialects for SQL.

Comment: "Removing the C tag from a question because it isn't about standard C [...] is a hostile act — it is not friendly or welcoming, nor is it helpful." Exactly.

Comment: I don't know two SQL service that are fully (at least for standard thing) compliant. They all want to be call SQL, even if no one follow the actual standard. That why put a SQL tag is not really useful without the information of what is the real service you use. C don't differ, if you happen to use a compiler who doesn't follow the C standard, the C tag don't provide useful information, it must be along with a other tag who specify the compiler you use. For exemple, [tag:c] [tag:arduino].

Answer (score 4):

The (now superseded, but that's what I have in easy HTML form) C11 standard says the following ([C11 4p6-7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6)):

> [...] A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.

and

> A conforming program is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.

A program that uses the GCC extension `__attribute__` is a conforming C program, because it is acceptable by GCC.

Even with its `__attribute__`, GCC is a conforming implementation, because all identifiers that start with double underscore are reserved for the implementation for any use.

A [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) would argue that this program very much is written in C and can and should be tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).